# How can I let Dependabot update yarn.lock file in a PR?

Tags: github, dependabot, yarn-v4

I have a repo set up with Dependabot in GitHub. The config file is:

```yaml
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "npm"
    directory: "apps"
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
    open-pull-requests-limit: 2
```

The PR can be created by Dependabot for updating a dependency version but it only changes the `package.json` file, not the `yarn.lock` file. I am using Node 18 and Yarn 4.

Based on [this doc](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file), the default version strategy should be `auto`. But it is not very clear about how to make it update `yarn.lock` file. It also doesn't mention what Yarn version we are using.

Below is an example of PR created by Dependabot:

[image]

Comment: Yarn v4 isn’t supported: https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/about-dependabot-version-updates

Comment: How does dependabot know what yarn version I am using in the repo?

Comment: I doubt it does, as such, but it doesn't know how to update the lockfile so it's _not updating the lockfile_. Tracking issue: https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/8610.